# How to get Class<?> through Element or TypeMirror

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a custom Annotation Processor

This is my annotation var

`Class<?> tableClass();`

Now I have got the `DeclaredType`,
and how can I get the `Class<?>` object which the `DeclaredType` refers to.

By the way, if annotation has a var of `Class<?>[]`, how could I get the class array?

Comment: Typically, you can't. You need get the [`AnnotationValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/lang/model/element/AnnotationValue.html) from the `AnnotationMirror` and call `getValue()` on it. The previously linked documentation explains what types that method can return. Note for an annotation element, it will return a `TypeMirror`. For an array (of any type) element, it will return a `List<? extends AnnotationValue>`; you can call `getValue()` on each `AnnotationValue` in the list to get the individual values.

Comment: So, if you had `@Foo(tableClass = Bar.class)`, then ultimately, you'd end up with a `TypeMirror` representing the `Bar` type. You then use that `TypeMirror` as needed.

Comment: I see, for example: A method "call()" in Bar.class, are there exists any ways to call this method in AnnotationProcessor?

Comment: Not that I know of, particularly not if `Bar` is a class being compiled. But... are you trying to create a _compile-time_ annotation processor (you seem to be, given your use of `DeclaredType`), or are you trying to create a _run-time_ annotation processor?

Comment: Thank you, yes I'm trying to create a compile-time annotation processor just like Android Jetpack or lombok.   Such as RoomDataBase, it could call methods annotated by @TypeConverter in compile-time, and generate final class files in project directory. I've tried to read the source code of these frameworks but failed. : (  If there is any way to solve this problem......?

Comment: Lombok is different from other annotation processors (it hacks the internals of the compiler to modify the source tree before it's actually compiled, allowing it to add getters, setters, etc.). I'm not familiar with Room's implementation, but from a quick perusal it appears that it generates code based on the annotations via the `Filer` (after validating the annotations and their element values). At run-time, it finds and loads the generated classes based on naming patterns (e.g., the name of the `@Database`-annotated class plus a known suffix).

Comment: Note it also seems to use the [Auto](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/main) and [JavaPoet](https://github.com/square/javapoet) libraries to make implementing an annotation processor and generating source code easier.

Comment: "_A method "call()" in Bar.class, are there exists any ways to call this method in AnnotationProcessor_" -- So, I guess it depends on what you mean by "call this method". You can certainly generate code that will call the method when executed (after compilation).

Comment: OK, I got it, anyway. thank you very much!!